# SQL Server queries to Snowsql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to convert the below SQL server queries to Snowflake queries.

How can I convert this to Snowflakesql format? I tried with casting as int,to_number but I was not successful. I am new to this.

Query1:

```
SELECT   convert(date, cast(p.yearnumber * 10000 + p.monthnumber * 100 + 1 as varchar(8)), 112) AS Month
FROM tablea m 
INNER JOIN tableb p 
  ON p.period >= m.MinimumPeriod 
  AND p.period <= m.MaximumPeriod
```

Query2:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(INT,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,a.Offset,pid+'-01')))*100 +CONVERT(INT,MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,a.Offset,pid+'-01'))) AS per_id
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you run these?

Comment: I'm sure the queries won't run, since they are SQL Server specific syntax, but what have you tried in Snowflake?  The documentation for Snowflake is very good, so perhaps looking up how date formatting is done would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I convert this to Snowflakesql format?

Instead of trying to translate the code 1:1 between platforms, I would first try to determine what it is actually doing.

```
SELECT convert(date, cast(p.yearnumber * 10000 + p.monthnumber * 100 + 1 as varchar(8)), 112
```

Starting from scratch:

```
SELECT  cast(p.yearnumber * 10000 + p.monthnumber * 100 + 1 as varchar(8))
FROM (SELECT 2021 AS yearnumber, 10 AS monthnumber) p
-- 20211001


SELECT convert(date, cast(p.yearnumber * 10000 + p.monthnumber * 100 + 1 as varchar(8)), 112)
FROM (SELECT 2021 AS yearnumber, 10 AS monthnumber) p
--2021-10-01
```

As we can see, we are building date based on year, month. In SQL Server we could use:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2021,10,1)
FROM (SELECT 2021 AS yearnumber, 10 AS monthnumber) p
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=334a5f487871e6ad893e68105745c077)**

---

And Snowflake supports [DATEFROMPARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html) exactly the same as SQL Server.

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(p.yearnumber, p.monthnumber, 1) AS Month
FROM tablea m 
INNER JOIN tableb p 
  ON p.period >= m.MinimumPeriod 
  AND p.period <= m.MaximumPeriod;
```

I am leaving second query as an exercise.

Comment: Got the query working for snowflake:    select 
cast(extract(year from DATEADD(month,a.offset,pid )) as int)*100  
+cast(extract(month from DATEADD(month,a.offset,pid  )) as int) 
AS Rpid
FROM 
(SELECT  -1 AS offset,date('2000-09','YYYY-MM') as pid ) a;;;;; Thanks